# SQL Server - How to change default data files destination when restoring?

Tags: sql-server

I have a database called 'AdvWorks'. 
I have a backup call 'BackupDB.bak'.

When I restore the BackupDB.bak over AdvWorks, SQL tries to overwrite the data files of the BackupDB rather than the AdvWorks data files. I have to change this everything and to me this makes no sense.

Can someone please tell me why it behaves like this?
And secondly, can this default location be changed to the restore db files rather than the backup db files?

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, this is the only behaviour that makes sense and doesn't risk causing damage. A *backup* is a backup of a *database*, not just a data file. It's supposed to restore *that* database in case of trouble. The only default file location that would make sense is the original file location. If you want to restore the database elsewhere, just click on the checkbox that allows you to specify a new folder.

Comment: If backup behaved the way you want, it would mean that it would decide to **overwrite** an existing database's files without warning or confirmation.

Comment: Thanks, this makes perfect sense now that I think about it. However, in my job there are myriad times we take a copy of different databases and restore them over new or different databases.

Comment: Just to add > You could argue that this default behavior is also risky. If I want to restore a Live database over a Test database (so we have a fresh copy), then there is the chance the live files are overwritten.

Comment: No it isn't. You have to explicitly say that you want to overwrite the database. Besides - restore. It's meant to *restore*, not copy. It's primary job is to *restore* a database to a previous state.

Comment: Besides, if you put your test and production database on the same server, you don't have a production  database at all. You have two test databases, one exposed to business users that contains production data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> , SQL tries to overwrite the data files of the BackupDB rather than the AdvWorks data files

This is because,the location is also copied in backup file

To overcome this,use `RESTORE WITH MOVE`..

```
RESTORE DATABASE MyNwind  
   FROM MyNwind_1  
   WITH NORECOVERY,  
   MOVE 'MyNwind_data_1' TO 'D:\MyData\MyNwind_data_1.mdf',   
   MOVE 'MyNwind_data_2' TO 'D:\MyData\MyNwind_data_2.ndf';
```

Comment: Thanks for this. So this step will always have to be taken? Or is there a way this default can be changed? I understand now why it does this, but for our local and testing environments I want to keep the default to go to the destination folder.

Comment: SQL restores(creates new database) by default to a path set (you can see that by right clicking server ),if you want to use new path while restoring ,you have to always use this option @PaulS

Comment: You can also use the `WITH REPLACE` option

Comment: @Hybris95:with replace,will replace current existing mdf,ldf for the db,i am not sure,if user is looking for that

Comment: `SQL tries to overwrite the data files of the BackupDB rather than the AdvWorks data files` to me, this sounds like it is the expected behavior, I'd say : `RESTORE DATABASE AdvWorks WITH REPLACE`